# Can attributes replace properties in a Protocol or superclass and if not why not?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I'm a little confused about why I'm getting a warning in Pycharm over replacing a property with an attribute.

Eg:

```py
from typing import Protocol

class Foo(Protocol):
    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        pass

class Bar(Foo):
    # I get a warning for the line below
    # Type of 'x' is incompatible with 'Foo' 
    x: int

    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x
```

What I don't understand is why I'm getting a warning over this.  To my eye it looks like a false-positive.  As far as I know the only practical difference is that `Bar.x` can be assigned to where `Foo.x` can't.  But adding capability such as adding methods wouldn't normally violate a protocol.

What am I missing here?  Is replacing a property with an attribute really incompatible with the protocol or superclass and if so why?

Comment: Note that you didn't include the `self` parameter to `Bar.__init__`, though; I think the error message is telling you that `int` is not compatible with `Foo` itself, not that there's a difference between `Foo.x` and `Bar.x`.

Comment: @chepner Woops. That's the danger of typing to type an SSCCE into stack overflow without going via a code editor.  I've corrected the question.

Comment: There is still a significant difference between a `property`-valued class attribute and an instance attribute, though, so I suspect that's relevant. I wonder if `mypy` simply makes more of an inference on the final result of `Bar().x` than PyCharm.

Comment: @chepner besides raising an exception when assigning to a property, I can't think of any interaction that would "misbehave" if you were otherwise interacting with an attribute.  To violate the protocol *some behaviour* must not conform, but I'm racking my brains for what it might be.

Comment: I think it's the fact that `Foo.x` has type `property`, not `int`. The type checker has to make the leap that if `f = Foo()`, then `f.x` is really `Foo.__dict__['x'].__get__(f, Foo)`, and *that* returns an `int`. It doesn't appear that PyCharm does that: it only sees that you are trying to replace something with a type that isn't a superclass of `int` with an `int`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the fact that `f.x` evaluates to an `int` is *not* a static property of your code, but a dynamic property based on the implementation of the descriptor `property`.

Comment: @chepner Interesting argument.  The counter argument is that [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol) could / should make it a static property of the code... assuming of course that `property` is properly type hinted (I'm not sure that it is).  IE the return types of the property functions via any generic type hinting on `property` could / should make them equivalent.

Comment: That's not something *Python* is responsible for. A descriptor is purely dynamic; it's the static type checker that has to recognize how `property` works as a special case (which is what I think `mypy` does).

Comment: If you redefine `property` to do something else, you do get an error in `mypy` that `x: int` conflicts with `x: Callable[[Foo], int]`. I've lost track of whether this is evidence for or against my theory, though. (Redefining `property` in Python is slightly different from redefining it in the interpreter, `mypy` can see the former redefinition.)

Comment: Static type hinting in a dynamic language is hard.

Answer (score -1):

(Update: the original code was missing `self`, and the similar error reported by `mypy` in that case made it seem like more than a typo.)

---

You didn't define `Bar.__init__` properly. `x` is interpreted as the parameter that receives an instance of `Bar` as its value, but you've annotated it with `int`.

```
class Bar(Foo):
    x: int

    def __init__(self, x:int):
        self.x = x
```

The problem is mainly with PyCharm's error message. `mypy` catches this by noting that `self` is either missing or mis-typed.

Comment: That's clearly a typo in the question. It doesn't explain why the warning on the line I've specified.  Even with the corrected `self` the problematic warning remains.

Comment: Then it would appear to be a bug in PyCharm's type checker. I had originally posted a comment regarding the different types that `Foo.x` (`property`) and `Bar.x` (non-existent, but interpreted as the type for an instance attribute), but I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: (The error message reported by `mypy` on your original code was similar enough to the error you reported that I thought the missing `self` was the cause.)

Comment: Fair enough.  Though in this context I did specify Pycharm ;-). Any leads you've got are welcome. It's good to know that other editors / linters don't report this.

Comment: I don't use PyCharm myself, but just based on the number of questions about it here, I don't consider it terribly reliable.